# Como puedo personalizar los rangos de una lista?

Tags: android

Tengo una app con una lista de articulos cargado de datos de un JSON (codigo, descripcion, precio ubicacion ) dentro de la lista hay articulos que tienen promociones y otros no.) MI idea es cambiar de color a los rangos que tienen promociones algo parecido con esta imagen...
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahi esta mi codigo ,filtre le resultado del JSON de todos los articulos que tienen promociones , luego no se como cambiar dichos rangos  en otro color..

```
protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
    prod = new ArrayList<>();
    lista_eligida = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lista);

    String url = "http://danbijann.freeiz.com/tareas.json";
    HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();
    JSONObject jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url);

    try {
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(String.valueOf(jsonStr));
        Log.e("JSON", String.valueOf(jsonStr));
        JSONArray contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray("PEDIDOS");
        for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

            String codig = c.getString("codigo");
            String des = c.getString("descrip");
            String prec = c.getString("precio");
            String cantidad = c.getString("cantidad");
            String ubica = c.getString("ubica");

            String prueba = "";
            if(objJson.has("prueba") && !objJson.isNull("prueba")){
                prueba = c.getString("prueba");
            }

            String promocion = "";
            if(objJson.has("promocion") && !objJson.isNull("promocion")) {
                promocion = c.getString("promocion");
            }

            String prueba2 = "";
            if(objJson.has("prueba2") && !objJson.isNull("prueba2")) {
                prueba2 = c.getString("prueba2");    
            }


            HashMap<String, String> contacto = new HashMap<>();
            contacto.put("codigo", codig);
            contacto.put("descrip", des);
            contacto.put("precio", prec);
            contacto.put("cantidad", cantidad);
            contacto.put("ubica", ubica);
            contacto.put("preuba", prueba);
            contacto.put("promocion", promocion);
            contacto.put("prueba2", prueba2);

            Log.d("ADAP", codig);
            Log.d("ADAP", des);
            Log.d("ADAP", prec);
            Log.d("ADAP", cantidad);
            Log.d("ADAP", ubica);

            prod.add(contacto);
        }
    } catch (final JSONException e) {
        e.getMessage();
    }
    return null;
}
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    if (pDialog.isShowing())
        pDialog.dismiss();
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    final ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(Prueba.this, prod,
            R.layout.item_carrito, new String[]{ "codigo", "descrip", "precio", "cantidad","ubica","prueba","promocion","prueba2"},
            new int[]{R.id.txtcodigo, R.id.txtdescrip, R.id.txtprecio, R.id.cantidad, R.id.txtubica, R.id.txtprueba, R.id.txtpromo, R.id.txtprueba2});
    lista_eligida.setAdapter(adapter);
    registerForContextMenu(lista_eligida);

}
```

Comment: Buenas, podrías crear tu propio `ListAdapter`, o cambiar a `RecyclerView` y al crear el `Adapter` del `RecyclerView`, cambiarle el color

Comment: Recomiendo hacer un `Adapter` personalizado e incluso como dice @JulianYbarra utilizar un `recyclerView` en lugar de `ListView`. Tal vez este tutorial te sea de ayuda, esta un poco viejo pero esencialmente es lo mismo [tutorial](https://gustavopeiretti.com/android-recyclerview-ejemplo-simple/)